# Write a SparseArray of Double to Parcel

Tags: android, sparse-matrix, parcelable

I have a `SparseArray` of `Double` and I have to write it to the Parcel.

Here is my code :

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    SparseArray<Double> spa = new SparseArray<>();
    spa.put(1, 0.8d);
    spa.put(5, 6.4d);
    spa.put(89, 0.8d);
    dest.writeSparseArray(spa);
}
```

This won't compile, with this error :

> **writeSparseArray (android.util.SparseArray<java.lang.Object**>) in
>   **Parcel** cannot be applied to
>   (android.util.SparseArray<java.lang.Double>)

Android Studio javadoc for `writeSparseArray()` tells me that it use `Parcel`'s `writeValue()`, and [the doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeValue(java.lang.Object)) at this method says that it should work :

> The given `Object` value may currently be one of the following types:
>   ..., `Double`, ...

For now, I have to copy my `SparseArray` to a `HashMap` an use `putSerializable()`, which I know is nearly an insult to sanity.

**How can I efficiently copy my Double SparseArray to the Parcel ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change from `SparseArray<Double>` to `SparseArray<Object>`.

Although `Double` is a descendant of `Object`, `SparseArray<Double>` is not considered a descendant of `SparseArray<Object>`, that's why you get compile time error.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I wonder why the signature is `SparseArray<Object>` and not `SparseArray<? extends Object>` though...